# Django вывод статьи в зависимости от значения поля в юзер-модели

Tags: django, django-model, django-template, django-urls, django-view

Есть модель `Task` и `Student`. Ниже код от моделей и т. д.

models.py

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('1', 'Активный'),
        ('2', 'Неактивный'),
    )
    GENDER = (
        ('1', 'Мужской'),
        ('2', 'Женский'),
        ('3', 'Другое'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = RandomSlugField(unique=True, exclude_lower=True, exclude_upper=True, length=6)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, blank=True, default='1')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, blank=False, default='3')
    classroom = models.ForeignKey('Classroom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

class Classroom(models.Model):
    CLASS_PROFILE = (
        ('a', 'А'),
        ('b', 'Б'),
        ('ab', 'АБ'),
    )
    class_num = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False)
    class_profile = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CLASS_PROFILE, default='a')
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField('Subject')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.class_num) + ' ' + str(self.class_profile) # ! Костыль пофиксить

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    files = models.FileField(blank=True)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey('Classroom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Task, Student 

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('all good. Students app here!')

def tasks_list(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    student = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tasks/tasks_list.html', {'tasks':tasks, 'student':student})

def task_detail(request, slug):
    task = Task.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'tasks/task_detail.html', {'task':task})
```

url.py (Может не надо, но я лучше добавлю)

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('tasks/', views.tasks_list, name='tasks_list'),
    path('tasks/<slug:slug>', views.task_detail, name='task_detail'),
]
```

Шаблон списка Tasks

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page_title %}
    Задания
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {% for task in tasks %}
        {% if student.classroom == task.classroom %}
            <div class="task">
                <h3><a href="">{{ task.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ task.body }}</p>
                <p>{{ task.classroom }}</p>
                <br>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            Неа, не работает
            {{ student.status }} <!-- Всё, что связано с Student не работает -->
            {{ user.username }} <!-- Работает ¯\\\_(ツ)_/¯ -->
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Пробовал и в `views student` присваивать объекты из соответствующей модели, и пытался вывести просто значение другого поля - ничего не получается. Либо я неправильно ее пытался вывести, либо Django её не может найти.

Comment: для кода на сайте есть специальный редактор и лучше его помещать именно туда, чем на посторонние сайты

Comment: Не знаю, просто видел, что ругались, мол, зачем весь код вставлять?!?! и т. п. Буду исправляться)

Comment: я имел ввиду, что маленький код лучше сюда, а если огромный, то соглашусь с мнением большинства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в models.py была связь Один-к-многим к user, а нужна была Один-к-одному. Когда это исправил, и переменные в шаблоне заработали и цикл поправил.

```py
user = OneToOne(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```